# declare global variable in seperate file nodejs+typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript4.0

I am new to typescript and this might be a noob question.

I want to extend global variable provided by nodejs.

As per this [blog](http://marcinbiernat.pl/2020/03/nodejs-globals/) I wrote this code and it is working

```
declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
      interface Global {
        appRoot: string;
      }
    }
  }
 
import path from "path";

global.appRoot = path.join(__dirname,'../');
console.log(global.appRoot)
```

but I want to take this global to separate file and if I move this to a new global.d.ts file

1. I dont know what to export
2. I am getting this error

> Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in
> external modules or ambient module declarations.

if do this

```
  declare module NodeJS {
    export interface Global {
      appRoot: string;
    }
  }
```

I get this error
Property 'appRoot' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'.

> Property 'appRoot' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'.

Comment: If my answer is not working, please consider updating your question with your tsconfig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of global declaration works always seems to depend on project setup. In your case, the following global.d.ts should work:

```
export {}; // make the file a module, to get rid of the warning

declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface Global {
            appRoot: string;
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure that only either one of the definitions is present.